# Linux Notebook with AMD Ryzen CPU, dedicated AMD GPU, USB4

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, linux, ryzen

I am using a Lenovo L14 AMD since quite a while, and while [Linux support was wonky in the beginning it finally works well](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDLaptops/comments/pdpfaq/lenovo_thinkpad_l14_gen2_amd_linux/). Using it for media creation work is not ideal though, as the CPU and GPU leave a lot to desire. Also, connectivity with fast external media is not given, hence I need to upgrade my system. I am researching Linux supported new Notebooks on the market which should provide AMD CPU, AMD GPU, and ideally USB4 connectivity.

Until now I found these devices to match the requirements

[HP EliteBook 865 G10, Ryzen](https://medium.com/@opengears/amd-ryzen-notebooks-for-influencers-creators-and-linux-enthusiasts-usb4-bluetooth-5-4-630a71ef8438)

- 2x USB4
- very pricey
- no dedicated GPU

[Razer Blade 14](https://www.pcworld.com/article/1976994/its-here-testing-the-first-amd-laptop-with-usb4.html)

- 2x USB4
- extremely pricey
- Nvidia RTX 4070 card

[ASUS TUF Gaming Advantage A16 Sandstorm](https://medium.com/@opengears/amd-ryzen-notebooks-for-influencers-creators-and-linux-enthusiasts-usb4-bluetooth-5-4-630a71ef8438)

- has 1x USB4
- Radeon RX 7600S GPU
- cheap(er)

[Framework Laptop](https://frame.work/at/en/marketplace/laptops)

- 2x USB4
- repairable
- unreleased (Q1 2024 batch)

Can it really be that there are so little USB4 capable Notebooks with AMD chipset out there? And there are no AMD notebooks with more than one USB4 port? Anyone with Linux experience reports on any of these mentioned notebooks? Other suggestions of hardware to look into?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is with USB4 is that originally it was Intel only (in the form of Thunderbolt) so right now there are indeed not a lot of computers that have that connector. I currently use the Framework 13 with an Intel CPU and runs really well with Ubuntu, but for the AMD version I don't have any experience although I would think it would run even better (because MESA). If you also need a dGPU I reccomend waiting for the Framework 16 since that one does support dGPU. The nice thing about the Framework though is that if you choose for the DIY edition you don't even have to pay for Windows, while for almost all other laptop models you do have to pay for Windows (although you might be able to get that money back in court if you tell the manufacturer beforehand that you don't want windows and they still charge you for it, and yes that has happened before)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! The HP EliteBook can be ordered without Windows (FreeDos) fyi. The framework 16 sounds exciting, but it ships in over 6 months (Q1/2024)

Comment: Yea that's the only bad thing about the Framework 16 that it's very popular and the early batches are sold out already